# Oracle SQL - break 1 row into 2 rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

```
create table members
(
  member_number   number(10),
  title           varchar2(5),
  lastname        varchar2(30),
  personal_email  varchar2(20),
  work_email      varchar2(20)
)
```

with the data

```
Insert into MEMBERS
   (MEMBER_NUMBER, TITLE, LASTNAME, PERSONAL_EMAIL, WORK_EMAIL)
 Values
   (11, 'MR', 'Dore', 'personal@email.com', 'work@email.com');
COMMIT;

  select member_number, title, lastname,
         decode (:pi_email,
                 'Work', work_email, personal_email) destination
    from members
   where member_number = 11
     and decode (:pi_email,
                 'Work', work_email, personal_email) is not null
union
  select member_number, title, lastname, work_email
    from members
   where member_number = 11
     and :pi_email = 'Both'
     and work_email is not null
```

Question:
Is it possible to re-write the code using 1 select and not using a UNION.

I want to be able to pass pi_email value of 'Work' and select the work_email, alternatively select the personal_email, however if I pass 'Both' I want to select both email addresses in 2 lines/rows.

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement,.  What results do you want?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can unpivot the data and then use a `where` clause.  In Oracle 12C+, you can do this using a lateral join:

```
select m.member_number, m.title, m.lastname, e.email
from members m cross join lateral
     (select 'work' as which, m.work_email as email from dual union all
      select 'personal' as which, m.personal_email from dual 
     ) e
where :pi_email in (e.which, 'both');
```

In earlier versions of Oracle, you can do something similar with `union all` in the `from` clause.

Comment: I am using 12c Enterprise Edition, I will try this out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about a CTE with additional column (`what` in my example, which tells what kind of an e-mail address is that)?

Sample data:

```
SQL> select * from members;

MEMBER_NUMBER TITLE LASTNAME   PERSONAL_EMAIL       WORK_EMAIL
------------- ----- ---------- -------------------- --------------------
           11 MR    Dore       personal@email.com   work@email.com
```

Query (runs in SQL*Plus) - fetch work e-mail address:

```
SQL> set ver off
SQL> with data as
  2    (select 'P' what, member_number, title, lastname, personal_email email
  3     from members
  4     union all
  5     select 'W' what, member_number, title, lastname, work_email     email
  6     from members
  7    )
  8  select member_number,
  9         title,
 10         lastname,
 11         email
 12  from data
 13  where member_number = &pi_memnum
 14    and (what = '&&pi_email' or '&&pi_email' is null);
Enter value for pi_memnum: 11
Enter value for pi_email: W

MEMBER_NUMBER TITLE LASTNAME   EMAIL
------------- ----- ---------- --------------------
           11 MR    Dore       work@email.com
```

Another example, which fetches both e-mail addresses (`what` is left NULL):

```
SQL> undefine pi_email
SQL>
SQL> /
Enter value for pi_memnum: 11
Enter value for pi_email:

MEMBER_NUMBER TITLE LASTNAME   EMAIL
------------- ----- ---------- --------------------
           11 MR    Dore       personal@email.com
           11 MR    Dore       work@email.com

SQL>
```

---

If you don't use SQL*Plus, the last two lines (i.e. the `where` clause) would be

```
where member_number = :pi_memnum
  and (what = :pi_email or :pi_email is null);
```

Comment: I need to read up on the below, this is very close to the 1 select I want, I am trying to stay away from using UNION.

SELECT member_number,
       title,
       lastname,
       personal_email destination
  FROM members UNPIVOT EXCLUDE NULLS (personal_email
               FOR (email)
               IN (personal_email, work_email))

Comment: Why do you find UNION *evil*?